# Postman SOAP request works, but CURL doesn't

Tags: php, curl, soap

I'm trying to implement the AAA Cooper Freight's SOAP API via PHP.
When I send XML request to http://wsportal.aaacooper.com:8188/wsportal20/wsGenEst, it via Postman, works fine, but when using CURL, it doesn't return anything

I use the direct url(from the wsdl file), because their WSDL file seems to be broken and its not working with it:
http://wsportal.aaacooper.com:8188/wsGenRateEstimate.wsdl

Here is screenshot from Postman(Working!)
[image]
and my php code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://wsportal.aaacooper.com:8188/wsportal20/wsGenEst" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $input_xml ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1')); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($data);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm using same XML string on both places.

Comment: 2 things, add to OP the error you are getting, "doesn't work" is not a good description :p.  2) On postman you send an XML with UTF-8 encoding but in curl the Content -type header says `charset=ISO-8859-1`. Server may or may not ignore that so it could be breaking the request.

Answer (score 3):

Postman can generate the PHP code for any given request using the `Code` button on the top right corner of the screen. A demonstration of this feature can be seen in the image below.

[image: Postman generated code]

Comment: I copied the code but not it shows `cURL Error #:couldn't connect to host` . Thanks for the info btw, didn't see that option.

Comment: Ok, maybe a firewall or proxy server blocks the request. If you have a proxy on your network, you must configure cURL accordingly. Also, a DNS or routing problem might cause the cURL request to fail.

Comment: The thing is, the same CURL Works with another SOAP service/wsdl